# Place a list in the middle of the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

I have an itemized list:

```
\begin{itemize}

    \item First item

    \item Second item

\end{itemize}
```

I'd like to place this list somewhere near the center of the page.  But, I still want the bullet points to be left aligned.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list has to span across the page boundary, then you can adjust `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` provided by [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) - set them to equal values:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=.4\linewidth,rightmargin=.4\linewidth]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

You could adjust the margins based on the width of the list items.

Answer (score 3):

Without guessing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\NewEnviron{centeritemize}{%
  \global\centeritemizewd=0pt
  \setbox0=\vbox{
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\centeritemizeitem}
    \BODY\item\centeritemize
  }
  \global\advance\centeritemizewd\labelwidth
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\centeritemizewd}
  \leftmargini=0pt
  \begin{itemize}
  \BODY
  \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}
\newdimen\centeritemizewd
\def\centeritemizeitem#1\item#2{%
  \setbox2=\hbox{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd2>\centeritemizewd
    \global\centeritemizewd=\wd2
  \fi
  \ifx#2\centeritemize
    % end the recursion
  \else
    \expandafter\centeritemizeitem
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{centeritemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{centeritemize}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Limitations: no blank lines are allowed in the `centeritemize` environment.

[image]

Don't use it. There's no reason to.

Comment: ... and page-breaking.

Comment: @Werner This might be solved by setting `\leftmargini` instead of using a `minipage`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}

    \item First item

    \item Second item

\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Most methods try to guess the width of the `\itemize` by trial and error. Here is another simple method that requires no guessing (making use of the powerfull `varwidth` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}

\newlength\mylen
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\textbullet\qquad Second item\end{varwidth}}
\setlength\mylen{\the\wd\mybox}

\vspace*{\fill}\centering
\parbox{\mylen}{%
\begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
\end{itemize}}
\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

OLD sol: Can try this (without changing the whole page size):

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}\centering
\parbox{3cm}{%
\begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
\end{itemize}}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

Giving:

[image]

Limitation here is guessing the `3cm` width.

Comment: Well, for `\hfill~` just use `\begin{center} .. \end{center}` and for `\vfill~` may be use `\vspace*{\fill} .. \vspace*{\fill}` but i'm not sure about a better workaround.

Comment: Since you agree with my suggestion, I updated my answer. Thanks @David Carlisle

Comment: yes I deleted my comments:-) (and added a missing `%`) +1 then (the `~` version is still in the second blovk

Comment: Yes, I edited this too.

Comment: `varwdith` is a good suggestion, but `\begin{center}
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item One
    \item Two and three
    \end{itemize}
  \end{varwidth}
\end{center}` seems to be a simpler way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two solutions, `emulating` the itemize environment with a `tabular` environment for short items, or with a `tabulary` environment, fixing the maximum width of items and automatic linebreaking at the prescribed width. It also  allows for `\par`s.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[textwidth = 16cm, nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabulary}{0.6\linewidth}{@{\textbullet\hskip\labelsep}L@{}}
  A very long first item, a very long first item, a very long first item, a very long first item, 
  \par
   To be continued… \\
  Second item \\
  A slightly longer third item
 \end{tabulary}
\end{center}

 \lipsum[3]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabulary}{0.6\linewidth}{@{\textbullet\hskip\labelsep}L@{}}
  A not so long first item\\
  Second item \\
  A slightly longer third item
 \end{tabulary}
\end{center}

 \lipsum[4]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet\hskip\labelsep}l@{}}
  A not so long first item\\
  Second item \\
  A slightly longer third item
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way of doing it:

```
\begin{itemize}

    \item \begin{center} $\vec{n}_{yz}=\langle 1,0,0 \rangle$ \end{center}
    \item \begin{center} $\vec{n}_{zx}=\langle 0,1,0 \rangle$ \end{center}
    \item \begin{center} $\vec{n}_{xy}=\langle 0,0,1 \rangle$ \end{center}

\end{itemize}
```